# CakePHP 3 AJAX POST not allowed and returns 403

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to create an action in CakePHP 3.4 to receive an AJAX POST request.
GET requests are OK.

I've added to my controller:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['fileUpload', 'openinghoursPlaces']);
}
```

as described in https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html

but nothing, it returns 403 on POST requests.

My action openinghoursPlaces actually returns an "OK" string.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

403 means unauthorized actions, so start by marking your actions as public

```
$this->Auth->allow(['fileUpload', 'openinghoursPlaces']);
```

If it works take a look at your "isAuthorized" action (Appcontroler.php), be sure you don't redirect to an unautorized action if the request is post.